# How long has Sabrina lived with her Aunts?

Tags: plot-explanation, sabrina-the-teenage-witch

In the television series *Sabrina, The Teenage Witch* at the start of the series how long has Sabrina been living with her aunts?

Her parents are divorced, and her aunts say that the reason she's living with them is because they are to teach her how to be a witch. But how long has she actually been living with them? She's supposed to be starting at a new school in the pilot, so I assume she only recently moved in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Probably less than a Year

From the [**Wikia**](http://sabrinatheteenagewitch.wikia.com/wiki/Sabrina_Spellman).

> **In her sophomore year of high school**, Sabrina's father, Edward, gets called away to the foreign services and her mother, Diana, goes on an archaelogical dig in Peru so she moves in with her zany aunts Zelda and Hilda in their Victorian house in Westbridge, a small suburb near Boston.

So, from my understanding, US High School sophmores are 15-16 and the show chronicles the adventures of Sabrina Spellman (played by Melissa Joan Hart), a girl who discovers on her **sixteenth birthday** that she is a witch.